# Is there any way to implement before and after view functionality in swift ios for side by side image comparison as we move the slider left or right?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

[Attached video here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hMTAI8nyMksB5-7GeG5X87ji_s9MKTtO/view?usp=sharing)

I want create this before and after view for side by side image comparison [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgg1t.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a layer mask.

Essentially:

```
private let maskLayer = CALayer()
maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
leftImage.layer.mask = maskLayer
var r = bounds
r.size.width = bounds.width * pct
maskLayer.frame = r
```

That will "clip" the image view and show only the portion covered by the mask layer.

Here's a complete example...

Using these "before" (left-side) and "after" (right-side) images:

[image]

[image]

With this sample custom view:

```
class RevealImageView: UIImageView {
    
    public var leftImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if let img = leftImage {
                leftImageLayer.contents = img.cgImage
            }
        }
    }
    public var rightImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if let img = rightImage {
                self.image = img
            }
        }
    }
    
    // private properties
    private let leftImageLayer = CALayer()
    private let maskLayer = CALayer()
    private let lineView = UIView()
    private var pct: CGFloat = 0.5 {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        // any opaque color
        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        leftImageLayer.mask = maskLayer
        // the "reveal" image layer
        layer.addSublayer(leftImageLayer)
        
        // the vertical line
        lineView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        addSubview(lineView)
        
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first
        else { return }
        let loc = t.location(in: self)
        pct = loc.x / bounds.width
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first
        else { return }
        let loc = t.location(in: self)
        pct = loc.x / bounds.width
    }
    
    private func updateView() {
        // move the vertical line to the touch point
        lineView.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.width * pct, y: bounds.minY, width: 1, height: bounds.height)
        
        // update the "left image" mask to the touch point
        var r = bounds
        r.size.width = bounds.width * pct
        
        // disable layer animation
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        maskLayer.frame = r
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        leftImageLayer.frame = bounds
        updateView()
    }
}
```

and this simple example controller:

```
class RevealImageTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let leftIMG = UIImage(named: "before"),
              let rightIMG = UIImage(named: "after")
        else {
            return
        }

        let revealView = RevealImageView()
        revealView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(revealView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            revealView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            revealView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            revealView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            // give reveal view the same aspect ratio as the image
            revealView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealView.widthAnchor, multiplier: leftIMG.size.height / leftIMG.size.width),
        ])
        
        revealView.leftImage = leftIMG
        revealView.rightImage = rightIMG
    }
    
}
```

We get this - the vertical line and the "viewable" portion of the images will move as you touch-and-drag:

[image]

[image]